# Opening a UIActivityIndicatorView after a UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet, uiactivityindicatorview

I have some destructive operations that need confirmation, and I'm using the UIActionSheet.

Inside the clickedButtonAtIndex I fire some lenghtly operations that need a UIActivityIndicatorView.

The problem is that I can't see the UIActivityIndicatorView until the UIActionSheet has closed, and this happens when the operation has finished.

Can I force to close the UIActionSheet even if the user has pressed some buttons and their clickedButtonAtIndex delegate has been fired ?

In pseudo code:

- User wants to do some destructive operation
- Request confirmation with a UIActionSheet
- The user says YES
- Delegate clickedButtonAtIndex fires and invokes a lenghtly operation
- This operation, the first thing that does is opening a UIActivityIndicatorView but because the UIActionSheet is active, I can't see until the end ...

thanks,

r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
CFRunLoopRunInMode(UITrackingRunLoopMode, 0.1, true);
```

to let the UI elements refresh before your lengthy calculation begins. Alternatively, you can use

```
-(void)doLengthyOperation {
   show_activity_indicator_view();
   [self performSelector:@selector(doRealLengthyOperation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
-(void)doRealLengthyOperation {
   // do the real lengthy operations.
}
```

Comment: This is not working: CFRunLoopRunInMode(UITrackingRunLoopMode, 0.1, true);

I'm going o try the other approach ...

thanks,

r.

Comment: @mongeta: Probably you need to run in `kCFRunLoopModeDefault` mode instead of `UITrackingRunLoopMode`. The other route is better though.

Comment: Thanks, finally a good combination of both solutions solved my problem. :-)